# WSE 3.0 + C# - Visual studio 2005

Tags: .net, soap, ws-security, wse3.0

I'm working on a .NET client to connect to an AXIS web service and as a part of this I'm trying to implement all the required security headers. My development environment is VS2005 and I'm using C#.

I've first downloaded soapUI and generated all the required security headers and started sending out messages, which works. So I know what I need to do (Sign the message, put it in `wsse:Security` header, encrypt the body and send it out)

So thinking it'd be simple enough, I've downloaded WSE3.0 from Microsoft and included it in my project. Now it's generating *something* but not with the security headers that I want. Specifically, I need to remove the webservice addressing headers (wsa:From, wsa:ReplyTo, wsa:Action), and the timestamp (wsu:Timestamp) but I'm unable to find any specific config settings in the wse3policycache.config file to remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSE is obsolete. Do not use it unless you have no other choices at all.

You would do better to get VS2010 Express or VS2008 Express and develop with those, rather than use obsolete code which is the next best thing to unsupported. For instance, WSE has no support inside of VS2008 or VS2010, and never will.

Comment: Ah, I've gone through a few questions here on SO where people were having loads of trouble with VS2008+WCF and were looking to get WSE back, but with the lack of documentation / support, maybe it's time to move on!

Comment: Yes, WSE is better forgotten. Take the effort you'd have spent making WSE work in VS2008/VS2010 and spend it on learning WCF, which does everything better than WSE.